# How do I refer to a value in a column in r?

Tags: r, dataframe, ggplot2, plot, graph

I am working with clinical data that includes the patient names as rows and the proteins as columns. An extra column includes the white cell count for the patients and the values are Low, Medium, and High. How do I create a table that only includes patients with low white cell count
[Here is an image of my table. The column names are protein IDs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Wb4m.png)

Comment: We cannot copy data from an image. Add them in a reproducible format which is easier to copy. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are familiar with `tidyverse`, this is one way you could do it;

```
df %>%
   filter(wcc_group == "Low")
```

Or, you could use `base-r`

```
df <- subset(df, subset = (wcc_group == "Low"))
```

Where `df` is the name of your `data.frame`.